# Typescript throws error when property p does not exist on type one of the OR-ed two classes

Tags: angular, typescript, aot, union-types

I have a component class, where I have a class property `renderContent` that can be one of the given 2 `type`s classes/models **`LessonPageType`** and **`TaskPageType`** based on the value I passed as `@Input()`. Below is my class component code:

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, HostListener, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LessonPageType, TaskPageType} from '../../models/types';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page-renderer',
  templateUrl: './page-renderer.component.html'
})
export class PageRendererComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() renderContent: LessonPageType | TaskPageType;
  @Input() submission: TaskSubmissionType;
}
```

**Problem: -**

I'm accessing `renderContent` variable object in my template as `renderContent?.accept_answer`. This `accept_answer` key is available in **TaskPageType** class but not on the other, which leads to the error below when the application builds under **AOT**. Is there a solution other than making the type of `renderContent` as `any` to work it fine?

**Error:-**

> ERROR in src/app/shared/components/page-renderer/page-renderer.component.html(16,17): : Property 'accepts_answer' does not exist on type 'LessonPageType | TaskPageType'.
>     Property 'accepts_answer' does not exist on type 'LessonPageType'.

Comment: What do you want to do if `renderContent` is LessonPageType?

Comment: @htn I have a single component for rendering the content. This component takes input either of  LessonPageType or TaskPageType. Both models have some similar properties in it, except 1 or 2 key.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @DanielB I'm using Angular 8.1.2

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a variable as a OR of two or more interfaces/classes, you'll only be able to access the properties that are shared between them. Possible solutions I would use:

- Define an optional `accept_answer` property in `LessonPageType`
- Make `LessonPageType` extend `TaskPageType` so it will have all of its properties, plus the custom ones you add
- The last option, declare `renderContent` as `any`

Hope it helps,

Comment: First solution will make the model impure. The second solution might violate the concept of creating models/Interfaces.

Comment: All options are bad

Comment: I don't see any trouble in one interface extending another one, as long as there's a relationship between them that makes it have sense (like a `Car` extending a `Vehicle`). As I don't know your particular business logic, perhaps this is not suitable for you...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to show in your template if you have `LessonPageType`.

if it's an empty string, you can do it like that:

```js
class PageRendererComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() renderContent: LessonPageType | TaskPageType;
  @Input() submission: TaskSubmissionType;

  get acceptAnswer(): string {
    return 'accept_answer' in this.renderContent ? this.renderContent.accept_answer : '';
  }
}
```

and use `acceptAnswer` in your template instead of `renderContent?.accept_answer`